# Any ways of creating QR code for CoreData UUID object?

Tags: swift, swiftui, qr-code, uuid

I'm trying to create qr code for UUID, but the main thing that stops me is that ways that I saw on creating qr codes require using String instead of UUID, so that's what I went for.

```
var uuid: UUID
var uuidString: {uuid} //cannot convert return expression of type 'UUID' to return type 'String'
```

Another option was

```
var uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

But It gave error later, when I was trying to use qr generating algorithm on practice (full qr gen code below)

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct QrCodeGen : View {
    let context = CIContext()
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    var uuid = UUID().uuidString
    var body : some View {
        Image(uiImage: createQrCodeImage(uuid))
    }
    
    func createQrCodeImage(_ uuid: String) -> UIImage{
        let data = Data(uuid.utf8)
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qrCodeImage = filter.outputImage{
            if let qrCodeCGImage = context.createCGImage(qrCodeImage, from: qrCodeImage.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage:  qrCodeCGImage)
            }
        }
            return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
    
}
```

Usage of generating qr:

```
NavigationLink(destination: QrCodeGen(uuid: Item.itemid)) //error: Value of type "NSManagedObject" has no member itemid
```

But later when showing text of Item.itemid everything is fine and recognised
Reeboting my machine and relaunching Xcode dint solve the issue also.

Comment: Not related to your question but you are using the wrong string encoding. it should be `isoLatin1` **To create a QR code from a string or URL, convert it to an NSData object using the NSISOLatin1StringEncoding string encoding.** https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator

Comment: Btw Returning an empty `UIImage` object in case of failure  instead of `nil` it is definitely a bad coding practice. I you are sure `UIImage(systemName: "xmark")` exists just force unwrap it

Comment: `Item` is the type. Not an instance of it. `itemid` is probably an instance property (not a static property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works to return the UUIDString for a UUID:

```
struct TestUUID {
    var uuid: UUID
    var uuidString: String {return uuid.uuidString}
}

let aTestUUID = TestUUID(uuid: UUID())

print(aTestUUID.uuidString)
```

It isn't clear to me what you're asking in the second part of your question. What error are you getting?

("It gave me error" isn't very helpful)

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked out for me. At that point error doesn't matter, it just went away when I used your solution. But error is under "Usage of generated QR"

Comment: You should accept my answer if it helped you.